# Marker saturation/value

Tags: java, android, colors, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I know how to make a marker icon in Android/Java ?

```
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE);
```

However,I want to change the color to change from black -> blue (or something) based on the location properties.

How do I change an icon's value to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set black color as marker using `BitmapDescriptorFactory`. This is because there is no way we can set brightness of a marker in `BitmapDescriptorFactory`.

But you can change the colors of marker by setting a value between 0.0f to 359.0f
in the `BitmapDescriptorFactory`.

For example, If you want Red, you can use

```
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(0.0f);
```

Like this you can set other color also

```
RED = 0.0F;
   ORANGE = 30.0F;
   YELLOW = 60.0F;
   GREEN = 120.0F;
   CYAN = 180.0F;
   AZURE = 210.0F;
   BLUE = 240.0F;
   VIOLET = 270.0F;
   MAGENTA = 300.0F;
   ROSE = 330.0F;
```

Please note that. these HUE are depends on which  Google Play Services installed on your device. So my suggestion is , use custom icon for markers

Comment: I know how to change the hue. What I'm asking for is to change the value. Are there image functions that would put a filter on a BitmapDescriptor or something?

Comment: For that you can use different BitmapDescriptor  for a marker .ie, if you want to change a marker color you can use  marker.setIcon( BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(50.0f);)

Comment: That would not change the value (darkness), just the hue.

Comment: in that case you have to use custom marker.  There is no way we can set brightness  in BitmapDescriptorFactory.

Answer (score 0):

For each location, you have to create a new icon of marker and pick a suitable color for it.

```
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(your_position)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .defaultMarker(your_color)));
```